# What does "f[]" mean in Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, function, syntax

When defining a Scala function

```
def f(x:Int):String="hello"
```

at REPL (in Intellij's worksheet) , I get

```
f: f[](val x: Int) => String
```

I do not follow that "f[]" part. Can anyone explain?

Comment: I can't reproduce with REPL 2.11.8, but this probably means that this method doesn't take (empty list of) [type parameters](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/polymorphic-methods.html)

Comment: What version are you using? Can't reproduce with Scala 2.12.3. Older versions of the Scala REPL produced descriptive output that looked sort of like Scala but wasn't. If you're using an older version (2.10 or earlier?), that could be the issue.

Comment: I can see it in my IntelliJ worksheet. It just means your method (technically not a function) takes no type parameters. Try this: `def f[A](x:A):String="hello"`